# How do I find the correct projection of a DEM to be used for viewshed analysis?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dem

My data download from Earthdata.nasa.gov for a DEM is in WGS84 CRS. I am aiming to create Viewshed using QGIS 3.14 but I am getting the below error message:

> Raster pixels are irregular in shape (probably due to incorrect
> projection)!

My assumption is that this error is because I cannot use a geographic CRS for View shed analysis.

Is there a particular CRS I should be projecting this DEM of Sinai, Israel so it can be used for my View shed analysis or any other suggestions to get rid of this error message?

Comment: Try reprojecting to some crs in meters, for example [32637](https://epsg.io/32637)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this

Comment: Here is a [list of suggestions](https://epsg.io/?q=Israel&page=1) from EPSG.io. [32636](https://epsg.io/32636) seems to be more commonly used in Isreal than 32637. However, I don't expect it to drastically change your result.

Comment: Thank you @ChloeG